# opencv error:Sizes of input arguments do not match

Tags: python, opencv, numpy, matplotlib

i m doing image blending using pyramid...
m getting an opencv error..
i m following the official opencv tutorials.
http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_tutorials.html

```
import cv2
import numpy as np,sys

A = cv2.imread('/home/grayhat/apple.jpg')
B = cv2.imread('/home/grayhat/orange.jpg')

# generate Gaussian pyramid for A
G = A.copy()
gpA = [G]
for i in xrange(6):
    G = cv2.pyrDown(G)
    gpA.append(G)

# generate Gaussian pyramid for B
G = B.copy()
gpB = [G]
for i in xrange(6):
    G = cv2.pyrDown(G)
    gpB.append(G)

# generate Laplacian Pyramid for A
lpA = [gpA[5]]
for i in xrange(5,0,-1):
   GE = cv2.pyrUp(gpA[i])
   L = cv2.subtract(gpA[i-1],GE)
   lpA.append(L)

# generate Laplacian Pyramid for B
lpB = [gpB[5]]
for i in xrange(5,0,-1):
    GE = cv2.pyrUp(gpB[i])
    L = cv2.subtract(gpB[i-1],GE)
    lpB.append(L)

# Now add left and right halves of images in each level
LS = []
for la,lb in zip(lpA,lpB):
    rows,cols,dpt = la.shape
    ls = np.hstack((la[:,0:cols/2], lb[:,cols/2:]))
    LS.append(ls)

# now reconstruct
ls_ = LS[0]
for i in xrange(1,6):
    ls_ = cv2.pyrUp(ls_)
    ls_ = cv2.add(ls_, LS[i])

# image with direct connecting each half
real = np.hstack((A[:,:cols/2],B[:,cols/2:]))

cv2.imwrite('Pyramid_blending2.jpg',ls_)
cv2.imwrite('Direct_blending.jpg',real)
```

following is the error:-

```
OpenCV Error: Sizes of input arguments do not match (The operation is neither 'array op array' (where arrays have the same size and the same number of channels), nor 'array op scalar', nor 'scalar op array') in arithm_op, file /build/buildd/opencv-2.4.8+dfsg1/modules/core/src/arithm.cpp, line 1287
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "programs/test11.py", line 25, in <module>
    L = cv2.subtract(gpA[i-1],GE)
cv2.error: /build/buildd/opencv-2.4.8+dfsg1/modules/core/src/arithm.cpp:1287: error: (-209) The operation is neither 'array op array' (where arrays have the same size and the same number of channels), nor 'array op scalar', nor 'scalar op array' in function arithm_op
```

Comment: So, what's the size of `gpA[i-1]` and `GE` at that line?/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It seems you are not generating your Gaussian pyramid properly here:

```
# generate Gaussian pyramid for A
G = A.copy()
gpA = [G]
for i in xrange(6):
    G = cv2.pyrDown(G)
    gpA.append(G)
```

According to OpenCV documentation on [cv2.pyrDown](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html#pyrdown), if you don't specify the `dstsize`, it will default to `((src.cols+1)/2, (src.rows+1)/2)`. BUT, you are always downsampling on the original `G` copy.
If I undertand correctly, I think you have to apply it on the last downsampled image:

```
# generate Gaussian pyramid for A
G = A.copy()
gpA = [G]
for i in xrange(6):
    G = cv2.pyrDown(gpA[i])
    gpA.append(G)
```

Obiously, the same applies to your *B pyramid*.

Now, your script will work if your images have an even shape but not with an odd shape because of how `cv2.pyrDown` computes the default size. In this case, you have to give to `cv2.pyrUp` the proper `dstsize` paramater according to the image you use to do the `cv2.substract` (or `cv2.add`).

```
# generate Laplacian Pyramid for A
lpA = [gpA[5]]
for i in xrange(5,0,-1):
    size = (gpA[i-1].shape[1], gpA[i-1].shape[0])
    GE = cv2.pyrUp(gpA[i], dstsize = size)
    L = cv2.subtract(gpA[i-1],GE)
    lpA.append(L)

# generate Laplacian Pyramid for B
lpB = [gpB[5]]
for i in xrange(5,0,-1):
    size = (gpB[i-1].shape[1], gpB[i-1].shape[0])
    GE = cv2.pyrUp(gpB[i], dstsize = size)
    L = cv2.subtract(gpB[i-1],GE)
    lpB.append(L)
```

Then, this point applies to the reconstruction part too:

```
# now reconstruct
ls_ = LS[0]
for i in xrange(1,6):
    size = (LS[i].shape[1], LS[i].shape[0])
    ls_ = cv2.pyrUp(ls_, dstsize = size)
    ls_ = cv2.add(ls_, LS[i])
```

Comment: @user3394251 Ok, I guess your images have an odd shape. I edited what worked in my test.

Comment: can you also tell me where to learn opencv?
i m a beginner in this. i have to develop a virtual mirror. 
any good resources will be really helpful.

Comment: @user3394251 Glad I can help. Well I only do basic stuff with OpenCV so I mainly use the doc and the python tutorial (as you mentioned) coupled with stackoverflow when I don't understand the input/output. But I guess a goog way to go is to write/look for a algorithm and then see what function is available for each part.

Comment: is there any video resources?

Comment: I've never worked with video but you can refer to the [official tutorial](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_video_display/py_video_display.html) or [one on the precedent version](http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.org/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_video/py_table_of_contents_video/py_table_of_contents_video.html) to see the basics.

Comment: I did exactly what you said @Gall, but im getting this error 
TypeError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__ method
at this line:
ls = np.hstack((la[:,0:cols/2], lb[:,cols/2:]))

Comment: @adeelz92 Well, this code was for Python 2 where the division operator is not a true division. In Python 3, you would need to use ``//`` to get the integer part.

Answer (score 1):

The following code would work for Python3, please try:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np,sys

A = cv2.imread('/home/grayhat/apple.jpg')
B = cv2.imread('/home/grayhat/orange.jpg')

# generate Gaussian pyramid for A
G = A.copy()
print(G)
gpA = [G]
for i in range(6):
    G = cv2.pyrDown(G)
    gpA.append(G)

# generate Gaussian pyramid for B
G = B.copy()
gpB = [G]
for i in range(6):
    G = cv2.pyrDown(G)
    gpB.append(G)

lpA = [gpA[5]]
for i in range(6,0,-1):
    print(i)
    GE = cv2.pyrUp(gpA[i])
    GE=cv2.resize(GE,gpA[i - 1].shape[-2::-1])
    L = cv2.subtract(gpA[i-1],GE)
    lpA.append(L)

# generate Laplacian Pyramid for B

lpB = [gpB[5]]
for i in range(6,0,-1):
    print(i)
    GE = cv2.pyrUp(gpB[i])
    GE = cv2.resize(GE, gpB[i - 1].shape[-2::-1])
    L = cv2.subtract(gpB[i-1],GE)
    print(L.shape)
    lpB.append(L)

# Now add left and right halves of images in each level
LS = []
lpAc=[]
for i in range(len(lpA)):
    b=cv2.resize(lpA[i],lpB[i].shape[-2::-1])
    lpAc.append(b)
print(len(lpAc))
print(len(lpB))
j=0
for i in zip(lpAc,lpB):
    la,lb = i
    rows,cols,dpt = la.shape
    ls = np.hstack((la[:,0:cols//2], lb[:,cols//2:]))
    j=j+1
    LS.append(ls)

ls_ = LS[0]
for i in range(1,6):
    ls_ = cv2.pyrUp(ls_)
    ls_= cv2.resize(ls_, LS[i].shape[-2::-1])
    ls_ = cv2.add(ls_, LS[i])

# image with direct connecting each half
B= cv2.resize(B, A.shape[-2::-1])
real = np.hstack((A[:,:cols//2],B[:,cols//2:]))
cv2.imwrite('Pyramid_blending2.jpg',ls_)
cv2.imwrite('Direct_blending.jpg',real)
```

Reference:

https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/dc/dff/tutorial_py_pyramids.html